# Create instance of all classes that extend a base class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a base class called `Editor`, I then have items that will extend that class. Is it possible for me to create an instance of all those classes that extend `Editor` without manually creating them all?

```
class Editor<T> {

}

class TransformEditor extends Editor<Transform> {

}

class SomethingEditor extends Editor<Something> {

}
```

So, in this example the code doesn't know `TransformEditor` exits, but it is in the codebase, so is it possible to do something where I can get a list of these items, then create an instance of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's no way to do this at runtime with TypeScript without adding additional code since there's no way to do this with JavaScript.

You could use [TypeScript's decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) to track the children. Here's an *extremely* simple example:

```
class Editor {}

const children = []; // This could be an object that maps parents to children

function TrackChild(constructor: Function) {
  // You could also add more fancy prototype/constructor shenanigans here
  children.push(constructor);
}

@TrackChild 
class TransformEditor extends Editor {}

@TrackChild
class SomethingEditor extends Editor {}

console.log(children);
```

This decorator could of course become much more sophisticated. Here's a very detailed example of [tracking a full genealogy with decorators](https://sizeof.io/es6-class-genealogy/)

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap all of these classes in a namespace and then you can iterate all of the exported items.
You can then check for each exported item if it is an instance of the `Editor` constructor.

Something like this:

```
namespace editors {
    export function getEditorClasses(): EditorConstructor<any>[] {
        let list = [];

        Object.keys(this).forEach(name => {
            let obj = this[name];

            if (obj.prototype instanceof editors.Editor) {
                list.push(obj);
            }
        });

        return list;
    }

    export interface EditorConstructor<T> {
        new(): Editor<T>;
    }

    export class Editor<T> {}

    export class TransformEditor extends Editor<string> {}

    export class SomethingEditor extends Editor<boolean> {}
}

console.log(editors.getEditorClasses()); // [function TransformEditor(), function SomethingEditor()]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20editors%20%7B%0A%09export%20function%20getEditorClasses()%3A%20EditorConstructor%3Cany%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09Object.keys(this).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09%09let%20obj%20%3D%20this%5Bname%5D%3B%0A%09%09%09%0A%09%09%09if%20(obj.prototype%20instanceof%20editors.Editor)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09list.push(obj)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D)%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09return%20list%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09export%20interface%20EditorConstructor%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09new()%3A%20Editor%3CT%3E%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09export%20class%20Editor%3CT%3E%20%7B%7D%0A%09%0A%09export%20class%20TransformEditor%20extends%20Editor%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%7D%0A%09%0A%09export%20class%20SomethingEditor%20extends%20Editor%3Cboolean%3E%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(editors.getEditorClasses())%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5Bfunction%20TransformEditor()%2C%20function%20SomethingEditor()%5D))